# Using $templateCache with template vs templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angular-templatecache

I am using grunts ng-template to store the html templates in the $templateCache.
The angular docs suggest that I can use the template like this:

```
myApp.component('myComponent', {
   templateUrl: 'templateId.html'
});
```

or like this:

```
 myApp.component('myComponent', {
   template: $templateCache.get('templateId.html')
});
```

What is the difference? I do not really like to inject $templateCache in every directive/component just to use this function. Is this about performance?

I have read this article: [How much of a performance difference is between template and templateUrl Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492581/how-much-of-a-performance-difference-is-between-template-and-templateurl-angular)
and if I am right then using a template (not templateUrl) is a little bit faster. Is this the only difference?

Comment: templateUrl is always asynchronously called, though if it's already in templateCache, it shouldn't be much a difference.

Comment: so there is a very good reason to use: $templateCache.get('templateId.html'),  if you want to see the difference then use your directive in a popup or any container that uses a positioning service.  If your directive affects the positioning of the container then it won't be loaded until the service has already calculated position.